# How to detect and extract hand written signature from document hard copy in react-native?

Tags: android, objective-c, react-native, image-processing, digital-signature

I'm creating an application that will have signed NDAs for each user, I want to sign those documents online, to do so I have implemented canvas to sign but it is not secure, now I'm planning on doing one of the following two options but could not find anything related.

> *Please note that I am looking for a solution in react native but I can also work with Java / Kotlin and Objective C/Swift and integrate
>   it in my application as a library and I can also do something like
>   uploading the document to a server and process it over there, but in
>   app solution is preferred.*

**Here are my two options**

1. I will show user the camera and they will hover their phone's camera on physical id or document with the signature and my camera component will some how ( using image processing or something ) detect the signature and save the cropped image in database or may be we can fix the type of document and scan only driving license or something an example would be like many mobile applications detect a credit card.
2. May be we can make the user sign a white paper and sign it and scan the white paper which may make it easier to detect the signature and capture the part of that white paper.

Thank you very much, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [react-native-signature-capture](http://%20https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture)

A simple modular component for react native to capture a signature as an image. User would sign on the app and when you press the save button it will return the base64 encoded png.

**Features**

- Performant Native Module
- Orientation Support Portrait/Landscape

[image]

Comment: OP said "I have implemented canvas to sign but it is not secure" so this is unnecessary.

Comment: I have already implemented this library but as I have already mentioned this is not secure I want the signature to be authenticated :)
Thank you anyway.